# Как на php скрыть "кнопку"

Tags: php, wordpress

Написал функцию для копки

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="nazvanie_knopkii" value="Поднять все мои записи" />
</form>
```

Это пхп кнопочка, как скрыть ее на час после клика?

```
<?php
# Если кнопка нажата
if( isset( $_POST['nazvanie_knopkii'] ) )
{
    echo my_dsfg();
    # Пример:
     echo 'Все ваши данные обновлены и занимают первые позиции!';
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="nazvanie_knopkii" value="Поднять все мои записи" />
</form>

function my_dsfg() {
  $currents_users = wp_get_current_user();
  global $wpdb; 
  $get_max_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT max(id) FROM wp_participants_database "); 
  $wpdb->query(" UPDATE wp_participants_database SET id = id + '$get_max_id' WHERE id_private = '$currents_users->id' ");
}
```

Читая код, можно понять, что "функция" поднимает запись на 1-вую позицию (надеюсь, знать "зачем" не надо), чтобы избавиться от юзеров, которые автокликом будут держать свои записи на первом месте, хочу скрывать эту кнопку, что делать UPDATE, к примеру, на час-два

Comment: допустим вы скрыли кнопку, что мешает юзеру продолжать слать запросы через `postman` напрямую?

Comment: @Сергей например проверка такой возможности?

Comment: если на сервере есть проверка, то что мешает вернуть html без этой кнопки, например так `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175753/how-to-embed-if-statement-inside-echo`